# Edit JsobValue in C++

Tags: c++, json

I have the json value

```
[{"line1":[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15],"line2":[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]},{"line1":[17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31],"line2":[18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32]},{"line1":[33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47],"line2":[34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48]},{"line1":[49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63],"line2":[50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64]},{"line1":[65,67],"line2":[66,68]}]
```

I need the following changes: in every line numbers since 45 should be removed to new array
Thye result should be as follows:

```
[{"line1":[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15],"line2":[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]},{"line1":[17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31],"line2":[18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32]},{"line1":[33,35,37,39,41,43],"line2":[34,36,38,40,42,44]},{"line1":[45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67],"line2":[46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68]}]
```

I will be grateful for any hints, because I still have very bad ideas in my head (for... for...)

Comment: what's your actual problem implementing this?

Comment: Did you use a library to manipulate your data ?

Comment: Can you describe the rules by which the second lists shall differ from the first lists? E.g. just *delete >44* won't do.